# Matlab find and print coordinates of array values

Tags: matlab

I have this array:

```
 A =

   30   18   40   58   26
   70   19   72   29   47
   14   48   40   14   48
   13   72   59   66   72
```

I want the program to find the coordinates of the values that are equal or bigger than 42 and then print those answers like this (line,row)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way SO works is that you show what you've tried and then describe what didn't work. Show us your code! This is a very simple task, I guess you have tried to solve it? If so show us what you've done already. Also see [ask]

Comment: See [this example on MATLAB's `find` method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budq84b-1).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A>42))
```

the first part `find(A>42)` returns the indices where the values in `A` are bigger than `42`.

The function `ind2sub` converts the indices to rows/columns based on the size of `A`.

Comment: No ind2sub required. You can use find with two outputs.